# Prove that if $A$ is diagonal, than $\operatorname{Adj}(A)$ is diagonal as well

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm not sure if my proof is formal enough, and I'd appreciate a review or if someone could write his/her proof of the statement. Here's how my proof goes:

Given a diagonal matrix $A \in M_n(F)$, we can say that $a_{ij}$, $1\le i\le n$ and $1\le j\le n$, being an entry of $A$, equals to $0$ if $i\ne j$. According to the definition of $\operatorname{Adj}(A)$, we can find it using the following formula:
$$[\operatorname{Adj}(A)]_{ij}=(−1)^i(−1)^j|A_{ji}|$$
$|A_{ji}|$ being the determinant of the minor matrix $A_{ji}$. Since only $a_{ii}$ can differ (either be an opening entry or $0$) from $0$, $\forall 1\le i\le n$, while all of the other entries are $0$, achieving $A_{ji}$ ($j\ne i$) requires removing column $i$ and row $j$ - and thus removing a column with the only potential opening entry at $a_{ii}$. This leaves $A_{ji}$ with a zeroes row where $a_{ii}$ was removed - and as known, a square matrix with a row/column of zeroes is not invertible $\iff |A_{ji}| = 0$. Which means:
$$[\operatorname{Adj}(A)]_{ij}=(−1)^i(−1)^j\cdot0=0\quad\forall i\ne j$$
just as required.

Comment: Use the caret ^ for exponents.

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct.

Comment: I've edited the question with MathJax - can you please double-check that this is done correctly?

Comment: @Widawensen: how would you exploit that ?

Comment: This proof is perfectly fine, I would just avoid writing $|A|$ and instead write $\det(A)$: namely, $|A|$ can be easily confused with a *matrix norm* (even though for the latter, double bars such as $||A||$ are more common).

Answer (score 1):

If you suppress a row, the corresponding column becomes all zeroes. If you suppress this column, you get a diagonal submatrix, and if you suppress another, the minor is perforce zero.

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&0&0&0\\0&b&0&0\\0&0&c&0\\0&0&0&d\end{pmatrix}\to
\begin{pmatrix}a&0&\color{red}0&0\\0&b&\color{red}0&0\\0&0&\color{red}0&d\end{pmatrix}\to
\begin{cases}\begin{pmatrix}a&0&0\\0&b&0\\0&0&d\end{pmatrix}\\\\\begin{pmatrix}a&0&\color{red}0\\0&b&\color{red}0\\0&0&\color{red}0\end{pmatrix}\end{cases}$$

---

**Formally:**

If we suppress the row $r$ and the column $c$,
$$M_{i\ne r,j\ne c}=(j\ne r) M_{i,j}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$A= \begin{pmatrix}A_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & A_2 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & A_n  \end{pmatrix}$$

Now, $\text{adj} A$ is the transpose of the cofactor matrix of $A$. If you carefully see, the cofactor of each element in the diagonal of $A$ is nothing but the product of the remaining entries taken with sign, and the cofactor of all zero entries (other than diagonal entries), will be $0$, because you could find one column or a row containing all $0$'s in it. Hence, it will be a diagonal matrix. Transpose of a diagonal matrix is again a diagonal matrix. So, done!